# Why does SELECT * FROM table WHERE value != '1' not return fields with NULL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data:

```
id | value
 1 | 1
 2 | NULL
 3 | NULL
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value != '1'
```

Result is empty.

Why does the query do not return row `2` and `3`?

Comment: NULL is equal to nothing, not even itself.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5718/2/0) 2 and 3 are not returned in this example...  My understanding was NULL will always evaluate to false when a comparison is made to it unless the null is evaluated using is null logic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `value` is equal to `NULL` the predicate becomes: `NULL != '1'`. This evaluates to `NULL`, not `true`, as one might expect.

This is the so-called [*three valued logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) of SQL: an expression evaluates to either true, or false, **or** `NULL`.

To correctly check against `NULL` you need to use `IS NULL`:

```
WHERE (value != '1') OR (value IS NULL)
```